# Error handling with "failed_when" doesn't work

Tags: ansible

I wish to create an ansible playbook to run on multiple servers in order to check for conformity to the compliance rules. Therefore the playbook is supposed to check whether several services are disabled and whether they are stopped. 
I do know that not all the services will be running or enabled on all machines. Therefore I wish to handle certain return codes within the playbook.

I tried the `failed_when` Statement for this Task. It seems the way to go as it allows to set which RCs to handle.

```
- hosts: server_group1
   remote_user: ansible
   tasks:
  - name: Stop services
    command: /bin/systemctl stop "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
         - cups
         - avahi
         - slapd
         - isc-dhcp-server
         - isc-dhcp-server6
         - nfs-server
         - rpcbind
         - bind9
         - vsftpd
         - dovecot
         - smbd
         - snmpd
         - squid

    register: output
    failed_when: "output.rc != 0 and output.rc != 1"
```

However the loop only works if I use `ignore_errors: True` which is not shown in the example code. 
I do know that I wish to catch RCs of 0 and 1 from the command executed by the playbook. But no matter what `failed_when` always generates a fatal error and my playbook fails. 
I also tried the failed_when line without the "" but that doesn't change a thing.
Something is missing, but I don't see what.

Any advice?

Comment: Stopping a service on a remote machine requires sudo privilege. Use `become: true` on your play. Moreover, you should use the [`systemd`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/systemd_module.html) or [`service`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_module.html) module rather than launching commands.

Comment: @Zeitounator: you are right - I do use the become method and execute it via sudo. But those lines are in the main playbook which references the Task playbooks like the one shown here.

Answer (score 1):

> Therefore the playbook is supposed to check whether several services are disabled and whether they are stopped.

Your playbook isn't doing either of these things.  If a service *exists*, whether or not it's running, then `systemctl stop <service>` will return successfully in most cases.  The only time you'll get a non-zero exit code is if either (a) the service does not exist or (b) systemd is unable to stop the service for some reason.

Note that calling `systemctl stop` has no effect on whether or not a service is disabled; with your current playbook, all those services would start back up the next time the host boots.

If your goal is not simply to *check* that services are stopped and disabled, but rather to *ensure* that services are stopped and disabled, you could do something like this:

```
- name: "Stop services"
  service:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    enabled: false
    state: stopped
  ignore_errors: true
  register: results
  loop:
    - cups
    - avahi
    - slapd
    - isc-dhcp-server
    - isc-dhcp-server6
    - nfs-server
    - rpcbind
    - bind9
    - vsftpd
    - dovecot
    - smbd
    - snmpd
    - squid
```

You probably *want* `ignore_errors: true` here, because you want run the task for every item in your list.

A different way of handling errors might be with something like:

```
failed_when: >-
  results is failed and
  "Could not find the requested service" not in results.msg|default('')
```

This would only fail the task if stopping the service failed for a reason *other* than the the fact that there was not matching service on the target host.

Comment: Thanks - that indeed works fine. And you are right about the "check". It is indeed intended that the playbooks stop and disable all the services.